# Python - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'obj' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, inheritance

I have to define a class method, that deletes the instance of that class. Skeleton of the code is as given below:

```
class baseClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fun(self):
        print 'Base Class'


class derivedClass(baseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super(derivedClass, self).__init__()

    def fun(self):
        print 'Derived class'

    def exitfun(self):
        print 'Delete Object Instance'
        del obj

obj = derivedClass()
obj.fun()
obj.exitfun()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\inheritance_del_instance.py", line 23, in <module>
obj.exitfun()
File "C:\Python27\inheritance_del_instance.py", line 19, in exitfun
del obj
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'obj' referenced before assignment
```

Other than calling,

```
del <object>
```

in Main, is there an alternate method to delete the instance of a class, by its member function. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible, other than maybe removing the entry corresponding to `self` from the `globals` dictionary. But even then there could be more references to that object, e.g. within lists or other dictionaries. What do you need this for, anyway?

Comment: `del obj` doesn't work because you haven't assigned a value to `obj`, it can't intuit that you're talking about the object itself.

Comment: @AnandSKumar not quite true. CPython uses reference counting; so as soon as the reference count reaches 0, the object will be deleted. It's only in case of circular references that the garbage collector kicks in, and the execution of that is indeed indeterminate.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a *garbage collector*, so an object is removed from memory when there are no more references pointing to it.
The keyword `del` simply removes the binding (reference) between a variable name and the object. If there are no more references to the object, its memory is freed by the garbage collector.
It makes no sense to use `del` to delete the object inside the object since `del` does not trigger any deletion per se.

Moreover in your code you have a syntax error, in fact the variable `obj` is not defined. You should use `self` to reference the object itself from within it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword `global` would solve your issue:

```
def exitfun(self):
    global obj
    del obj
```

However, it is probably not what you want to do. In order to define a class method, you need the [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator. Also, you could save the instance at class level so you don't have to access it through the `globals`:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        type(self).instance = self

    def say_hello(self):
        print 'Hello!'

    @classmethod
    def remove_instance(cls):
        del cls.instance

Test()
Test.instance.say_hello()
Test.remove_instance()
```